# In selenium web driver, is there any tool to fetch css selector value?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

In  selenium web driver, is there any tool to fetch css selector value ?
For xpath by inspect element we are ale to copy xpath easily.
how to fetch css selector values ?When we are identifying web element by css selector value?

Comment: It is the same as you select xpath. you have a copy css path, when you right click on that elements tag

Comment: thanks .. I have observed that iframes are getting identified by using findElement(By. CSSSelector) more precisely than by Xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use fireBug for this purposes:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot .. its working..thanks .. I have observed that iframes are getting identified by using findElement(By. CSSSelector) more precisely than by Xpath.